# extract information from single cells from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to pull specific information from the table below to use in other functions. For example extracting the volume on 1/4/16 to see if the volume traded is > 1 million. Any thoughts on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web   # Package and modules for importing data; this code may change depending on pandas version
import datetime
1, 2016
start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

apple = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)

type(apple)
apple.head()
```

Results:
[image: Results]

Comment: `apple.loc['2016-04-01','Volume']` will return the volume for that date, assuming your date is yyyy-mm-dd format, doing `apple.loc['2016-04-01','Volume']>1000000` will give you a True or False

Comment: Thank you @EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datareader will return a df with a datetimeIndex, you can use [partial datetime string matching](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) to give you the specific row and column using `loc`:

```
apple.loc['2016-04-01','Volume']
```

To test whether this is larger than 1 million, just compare it:

```
apple.loc['2016-04-01','Volume'] > 1000000
```

which will return `True` or `False`